# caring or care, warm or warmly

Tags: grammar

A friend asked me if there was any grammatical error in the sentences:

'Thank you so much for taking caring :) please, get dressed warm, too :)'

I told him that the 'caring' should be 'care' and the 'warm' should be 'warmly', according to my English knowledge.

Then my friend told me that the sentences were from an Australian, an English native speaker.

So, are they errors or not?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you that the first is an error. "Take care" is both grammatical and idiomatic. The error may come from the fact that "caring," as a gerund, could function as a noun, although not in "taking caring."

The second example, "get dressed warm," is less clear. The adverb "warmly" seems to be needed to modify the verb "get dressed." However, the speaker is not saying to perform that action 'in a warm way.' Rather, they are saying, essentially, 'put on warm clothes.' The use of the adjective "warm" in "get dressed warm" reflects that. To say to someone "It's cold out today—dress warm!" is common and idiomatic, even though saying "It's cold out today—put on some warm clothes!" is more precise.

Comment: 'Dress warmly' is idiomatic, and an idiom (as the adverb perversely describes the result rather than the actions involved in dressing). It's similar to a transferred epithet in say 'It was a proud day for her parents' (_they_ were proud, not the 24 hours or whatever in question). 'Dress casually' is a similar idiom.

Comment: Good point! Does the verb "get dressed," from the OP's question change that?

Comment: 'Get dressed warmly' sounds much less natural to my ears. It _does_ seem to be creeping in, probably as a result of squishing.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: I guess you can match up verb and adverb with "Dress for warmth" which ironically has about the same meaning as "Dress for cold'

Answer (score 0):

> 'Thank you so much for taking caring :) please, get dressed warm, too
> :)'

Obviously (to me, at least), this is a response (in kind) to a request to "dress warm".  Hence, the "too" in the response.  One can imagine a corrected conversation like the following:

```
A:  We'll be waiting for you to get here - be sure to dress warm. 

B: Thank you so much for caring, and please (you) dress warm too.
```